# How can I get the MAC address of a catched packet?

Tags: c#, networking, pcap.net

I'm trying to build kind of a sniffer to catch wifi probe requests.

With Wireshark, I simply set a filter like `eth.type eq 0x0806 and eth.dst eq ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff` that tells me I'm listening on the ARP protocol all the broadcast packets. I haven't found how to monitor the signal strength yet, but maybe I'll find it one day...

I'd like to do the same with Pcap.Net. So once a packet has been catched, I look at

```
//Check if the packet is Ethernet
if (packet.DataLink.Kind == DataLinkKind.Ethernet)
{
   //Check if the Ethernet packet is ARP
   if (packet.Ethernet.EtherType == EthernetType.Arp)
   {
      [...]
   }
}
```

but whereas packets are catched with Wireshark, nothing is catched with my C# code.

Another question, how to get the MAC address of the source of a packet ? How to get the signal strength with a wireless device ?

Comment: Do you catch packets if you remove both if statements?

Comment: MAC addresses are in the frame header, not the packet header. Frames have layer-2 (MAC) addresses in their headers, packets have layer-3 (IP) addresses in their headers, and segments have layer-4 (port) addresses in their headers. Frames encapsulate packets which encapsulate segments which encapsulate application data. You should study the [OSI Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model#Description_of_OSI_layers) when you want to do this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

As far as **getting the MAC address** is concerned, maybe this suggestion of mine can help you. Currently *I'm coding a sniffer using pcap.net*. It is working fine on my LAN connection. But my code is not capturing any traffic when a laptop is connected with a wifi network. It once did but in the last couple of attempts it just failed to capture any kind of traffic. And I think that's pretty obvious because

> pcap.net doesn't include any AirPcap features.

By the way, I hope that you've seen pcap.net's sample code. There they use a function called

```
... ... PacketHandler(Packet packet){ ... }
```

Inside this I added these two lines. And it is working fine for me.

```
private void PacketHandler(Packet packet)
{
    string sourceMac = packet.Ethernet.Source.ToString();
    string destinationMac = packet.Ethernet.Destination.ToString();
    //--more code
}
```

For now it is doing it's job. I've tested my sniffer along with NetworkMiner( another sniffer project in C# which is far better than mine :v). I tested it a lot, still doing it, and so far I've no issues.